# Where should I sign on this check?

Tags: check

I received a refund check from my credit card company. I would like to deposit to my bank account online. But I wonder where I can sign my name, since I don't see any hint on the back of the check.

[image]

Comment: General rule, sign on the opposite side (left side) of the location of the signature on the front (right side).

Comment: @user14218: then what you suggest is the shaded area? That is quite different from what Joe suggested.s

Answer (score 3):

[image: check]

This is where I would sign the check.

Comment: thanks. Why is it? What is the purpose of the shaded area on the left?

Comment: This is likely one of the security measures of the check. Endorsements usually go on the right (if you put the MICR print at the bottom) of the back of the check.

Comment: Also try to sign it the same *way* that Joe did.  That would be hilarious.